# How To close a userControl using command button

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, command

I'm using 3 files:

1-) Simple.xaml, it contains

```
<Button x:Name="OkButton"
        Command="{Binding OkSettingsCommand}"
        IsDefault="True"
        Content="OK" />
```

2-) Simple.xaml.cs ... it's empty, except the constructor that has an `InitializeComponent()` method

3-) SimpleViewModel ... that has an `ICommand OkSettingsCommand;`
that is initialized in the constructor

```
OkSettingsCommand = new ICommand(OnOKSettings);
```

using this function:

```
public void OnOKSettings()
{

}
```

How can I close the usercontrol after the button is clicked?

Comment: you mean closing the window in which you have placed the usercontrol?

Comment: yes, i'm a new WPF's developer

Answer (score 0):

just  try this

Create Close Behavior like this

```
public static class WindowCloseBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty =
             DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(WindowCloseBehavior),
             new PropertyMetadata(IsOpenChanged));

    private static void IsOpenChanged(DependencyObject obj,
                                      DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Window window = Window.GetWindow(obj);

        if (window != null && ((bool)args.NewValue))
            window.Close();
    }

    public static bool GetIsOpen(Window target)
    {
        return (bool)target.GetValue(IsOpenProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsOpen(Window target, bool value)
    {
        target.SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Create a property in View Model let it be

```
 private bool closeMe=false ;
    public bool CloseMe
    {
        get
        {
            return closeMe;
        }
        set
        {
            closeMe = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CloseMe");
        }
    }
```

and in the View just bind the CloseMe value into the Behavior . When you click on the Button make the CloseMe = True and this will close the current window

eg

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Behavior="clr-namespace:WpfApplication12"
Behavior:WindowCloseBehavior.IsOpen="{Binding CloseMe}"       
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CloseMe}" Content="Close" Margin="5"></CheckBox>
</Grid>
```